# CSSTransition not importing - type is invalid

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I've installed react-transition-group and am calling it with:

```
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
```

I am then using it like this:

```
const PageFade = (props) => (
<CSSTransition 
  {...props}
  classNames="fadeTranslate"
  timeout={1000}
  mountOnEnter={true}
  unmountOnExit={true} />
)
```

But on mounting the app I'm getting an error when calling the component:

[image: error]

I've tried installing react-transition-group on both an existing project and a new one, and exactly the same thing happens.

Comment: can you post some more code as context

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all of props.children are not undefined? If you passed some undefined childern for the componet you'll get this error. Component must be string, class/function or null.